# Reading list of object

Tags: objective-c, vb.net, macos, web-services

I created a web service using vb.net in IIS that selects data from database and returns a List of objects with the results.

Is it possible to read that list of objects with a program made in MAC OS X that interacts with the method of the  IIS web service?

Another option is use text files, but would be more effective using objects

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at the FAQ about some tips how to post concrete programming questions, such as *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."* - (I assume that "Yes, it is possible" is not the answer you are looking for :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but there is no out-of-the-box solution.

Your options are:

- Take a look at [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). It's cross-platform .NET framework implementation. You can write program for MAC OS X here and it seems to be the simplest way to go. However I'm unaware of the compatibility between Mono and Microsoft's CLR so you have to check yourself.
- You could also possibly run your original service under Mono in which case it would be very simple. The problem is Mono does not cover 100% of the whole .NET framework.
- Introduce [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) on service side and deserialization on MAC OS side. For example if you are be able to serialize your objects to strings, you can simply deserialize them on any platform.
- Theoretically you could implement your own Object deserializer directly from your existing service. But in practice it would be almost impossible. You would have to handle so many cases, cross-platform issues and much, much, much worse things. I mention this only for completeness of the list. DO NOT go this way.

**Appendix:**

You must realize, what your service actually sends. It actually sends just some sequence of bits. Computer must correctly parse them to reconstruct original objects. This is tightly related to what `Object` is in memory. It's memory image depends on the CLR implementation. Without equivalent CLR you won't be able to simply read `Object` from source CLR.

So your task is to ensure you are able to reconstruct the objects

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. I will try to serialize/deserialize and later i will tell you the result. Thanks one more time.